# find - I need to get the name of the package from a list of RPM

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have a folder with several RPM and want to return just the name of the package.

eg.

```
./nodejs-6.14.3-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

I want just to get

```
nodejs
```

The directory appear like this:

```
./http-parser-2.7.1-5.el7_4.x86_64
./libicu-50.1.2-15.el7.x86_64
./libuv-1.22.0-1.el7.x86_64
```

I want this output:

```
http-parser
libicu
libuv
```

Comment: Do you have several different RPM packages in the directory and want to get the only the first from all of them?

Comment: I edited the question to answer this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
rpm -q --qf "%{NAME}\n" -p *.rpm
```

Comment: This couldn't be more accurate!